# Is there a good web front end to network shares

Tags: file-sharing, search

My question is an offshoot of this question ([Best Pratices for a Network File Share?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36704/best-pratices-for-a-network-file-share)). I feel like this has to have been asked, but I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

We are prepared to take the scorched earth path to fix our 8 years of "cruft" (per the suggestion of the cited question), but we also would like to make searching a bit easier. I have to feel like there is a better way access/manage/search a organization file share instead of having users SSH in or access through SMB.

So my question is broad, but what is the best way to run an organization file share?

Comment: [The best approach to run an organization file share is... to ***not*** run an organization file share](http://serverfault.com/a/577912/118258).  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, which seems like a distinct possibility.

Comment: I guess I should have specified this, but we have a separate network that we do most of our work on due to sensitivities and all that. So transferring data to our closed network takes a non trival amount of time.